# How to use time as x axis for seaborn.scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, scatter-plot

I have a simple dataframe with the time as index and dummy values as example.

[image: my sample]

I did a simple scatter plot as you see here:

[image]

Simple question: How to adjust the `xaxis`, so that all time values from 00:00 to 23:00 are visible in the `xaxis`? The rest of the plot is fine, it shows all the datapoints, it is just the labeling. Tried different things but didn't work out.

All my code so far is:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import time

data = []
for i in range(0, 24):
    temp_list = []
    temp_list.append(time(i))
    temp_list.append(i)
    data.append(temp_list)

my_df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["time", "values"])    
my_df.set_index(['time'],inplace=True)
my_df
fig = sns.scatterplot(x=my_df.index, y=my_df['values'])
fig.set(xlabel='time', ylabel='values')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you're gonna have to go down to the matplotlib level for this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
from datetime import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = []
for i in range(0, 24):
    temp_list = []
    temp_list.append(time(i))
    temp_list.append(i)
    data.append(temp_list)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["time", "values"])  
df.time = pd.to_datetime(df.time, format='%H:%M:%S')
df.set_index(['time'],inplace=True)
ax = sns.scatterplot(x=df.index, y=df["values"])
ax.set(xlabel="time", ylabel="measured values")
ax.set_xlim(df.index[0], df.index[-1])
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%H:%M:%S"))
ax.tick_params(axis="x", rotation=45)
```

This produces

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i think you have 2 options:

1. convert the time to hour only, for that just extract the hour to new column in your df

> df['hour_'] = datetime.hour

than use it as your xaxis

2. if you need the time in the format you described, it may cause you a visibility problem in which timestamps will overlay each other. i'm using the

> plt.xticks(rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
>
> ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(12))

so first i rotate the text then i'm limiting the ticks number.

here is a full script where i used it:

```
sns.set()
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
sns.axes_style("whitegrid")

for k, g in df_forPlots.groupby('your_column'):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
    wide_df = g[['x', 'y', 'z']]
    wide_df.set_index(['x'], inplace=True)
    ax = sns.lineplot(data=wide_df)
    plt.xticks(rotation=45,
                   horizontalalignment='right')
    ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(14))
    ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.MaxNLocator(35))
    plt.title(f"your {k} in somthing{g.z.unique()}")
    plt.tight_layout()
```

hope i halped